# Maximum amount of tries to pick a red marble in a bag of 99 other black marbles (with replacement).

Tags: probability

I have a bag of 100 marbles, 99 black, 1 red. 
What is the maximum amount of tries it would take to pick the red marble assuming you place the marble back in the bag after your pick it up?

I know that the chance is 1%, so the average amount of tries in a normal distribution would be 100 to get the red marble. However you cannot be sure that you will have picked the red marble in the first 100 tries, 200 tries, etc. But as the tries increase, the probability of not having picked the red marble goes down increasingly.

At what point would it be considered impossible not to have picked a red marble?

Comment: While the probability of "not having picked the red marble goes down" and approaches zero as the number of tries goes to infinity, it never reaches zero.  It would therefore never "be considered impossible," only increasingly unlikely (not to have picked the one red marble at some point).

Comment: The probability of picking the never picking the red marble in $n$ tries decreases as $n$ increases, but it never gets to 0.  There is no "maximum number of tries."

Comment: Many things are considered impossible due to an incredibly low probability, wouldn't the same thing apply to an incredibly near to 100% probability?

Comment: You are free to "consider impossible" whatever outcomes you please.  To mathematicians impossibility means absolutely impossible, a much stricter conclusion even than an event of probability zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you define "impossible".

Colloquially speaking, you could define it to mean if the chance is less than some tiny $\epsilon$, then it is "impossible". 
Then you could solve for the number of picks that would satisfy that.
Most people would probably be unsatisfied with that though. (Even if $\epsilon=10^{-1000}$ the event *could* still technically happen)

In stricter sense of the word, one might ask for the probability to be $0$. 
This is not miniscule; it means literally zero.
In this case, the number of picks would have to go to infinity; in the situation described, this will *never* happen, because there will always be a non-zero chance of picking a string of one color, no matter how long that string is. No matter how small $0.99^n$ is (or how large $n$ is), the probability is positive.

In fact, for me personally, even zero probability is not strong enough for me to call an event "impossible". For instance, consider choosing a real number $c\in\mathbb{R}$ uniformly in the interval $[7,13]$. What is the probability of choosing *exactly* $c=9.713$? It is **zero**. But is it *possible*? Yes. It is a number inside the interval. To me, therefore, it is not *impossible*. 
Impossible is a bit of a high bar in that sense :D

Comment: Thanks! Helped me improve my understanding of "impossible". So I guess the answer really is never then.

Answer (score 1):

You can never be certain to pick the red marble, of course.  At every step there are black marbles.

In fact, you can never be certain to pick a *black* marble either, of course.  It is possible (though unlikely) you keep picking the sole red marble.  The chance of that, over $n$ picks, is of course $0.01^n$.

Comment: Since a lot of things are considered impossible because the probability is immensely minuscule, I thought the same thing would apply to a near 100% probability. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes.  It is wrong.  For any given number of tries, $n$, there is a chance you will not pick the red ball:  $P=.99^n$.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is very very short. Please consider making an [edit] to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

Probability for obtaining a red marble at least one time in $n$ tries is

$1-0.99^n$

for $10$ tries, it is $0.095$
For $100$ tries, it is $0.633$
For $1000$ tries, it is $0.999$

But we cannot define maximum accurately.